# I cannot seem to have the numbers decimals removed from the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

This might be pretty basic, but my code seems to have a few errors or expectations that might not work for me. Some background information: My code was created so that it asks the user for an integer. Then the user's input will be analyzed and will show the user an output of numbers that multiplied together will equal the user's input.

**Expectation**

Input: 7
Output(In console): (1,7)(7,1).

But instead, my code also inputs the decimals that equal the user's input.

**Reality**

Input: 7
Output: (1.1666666666666667, 6), (1.4, 5), (1.75, 4), (2.3333333333333335, 3), (3.5, 2), (7, 1), (Infinity, 0).

```
     var numInput= parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number larger than 1"));
        //This asks the user for the input 
    var valueArray = [];//This is the empty array we are going to use in the further code. 
            if(numInput <= 0 || numInput <= 1) {
                 console.log("Goodbye!")
        }//This line is an if loop which if the user inputs 0 or 1 then the code will end. 
   
        while(numInput > 0) {// This while loop is there so that the user can input as many numbers he wants 
         var valueArray = [];//Now the numbers are inside this empty array
         var numInput = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number larger than 1"));
   
         for (var iterator = 0; iterator < numInput; ++iterator) {//This for loop is the calculation, for when a = 1, the a has a greater value then 
           var valueSubtracted = numInput / iterator //This is where the variable subtracts the orignal value n so that we have something along the lines of (1,6) instead (1,7)
           valueArray.unshift(valueSubtracted + ", " + iterator ); //This just moves the answers into a concantination, and moves into the array
           }
        
     
        console.log("The additive combinations are: " + "(" + valueArray.join("), (") + "). ");
       }
```

All I really want is for the decimals to be removed and the number associated with it. For example:

Input: 7
Output: ***(1.1666666666666667, 6)***, ***(1.4, 5),*** ***(1.75, 4),*** ***(2.3333333333333335, 3)***, ***(3.5, 2),*** (7, 1), ***(Infinity, 0).***

Note that above: the bolded and italicized are supposed to be removed from the array.
[This is what it looks like in the console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwbaB.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should check if it's divisiable by the integer. To do so, use `n % m === 0` and check it in `if`-clause. It should be created inside `for`-loop.
Also: Doing zero division will not cause error. Instead it, it returns `Infinity`. Consider change start value to `1` in the `for`-loop to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better answer.

**Code:**

```js
while (true) {
    const numInput = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number larger than 1").replace(/\D/g, ""));
    if (numInput > 1) {
        const valueArray = [];
        for (let iterator = 1; iterator <= numInput; iterator++) {
            const valueDivided = ((numInput / iterator) % 1 === 0) ? (numInput / iterator) : false
            if (valueDivided) valueArray.unshift(`(${valueDivided}, ${iterator})`);
        }
        console.log(`The additive combinations are: ${valueArray.join(",")}`)
        continue;
    }
    console.log("Goodbye!")
}
```

**Breakdown:**

1. I used `const` and `let` instead of `var`
2. Infinite loop:

```js
while (true) // will keep repeating the same process until user clicks "Cancel"
```

3. Clean before parsing

```js
const numInput = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number larger than 1").replace(/\D/g, ""));
// uses RegEx to remove any non-numeric values
// parseInt() to get integer from prompt text
```

`if` the number is not larger than 1 `console.log("Goodbye!")`

4. used `let` instead of `var` in the `for` loop and replace `++iterator` with `iterator++`... the difference is that `++iterator` first increments by 1 *THEN* the variable can be used.
   Also, to answer your second comment on my first answer, it only logged (1,7) and not (7,1) because you had `iterator < numInput` so the loop couldn't reach 7, it stopped at 6. I changed it to `iterator <= numInput` instead.
5. calculate the possible divisions:

```js
const valueDivided = ((numInput / iterator) % 1 === 0) ? (numInput / iterator) : false
// if the value is a normal number return it, else return false
```

6. 

```js
// only add to the array if truthy
if (valueDivided) valueArray.unshift(`(${valueDivided}, ${iterator})`)

// Normal numbers with the exception of 0 are truthy values, which means if(1) returns true... if(0) returns false
// I used template literals `${dynamic} text ${dynamic}`
// so any added value will be like: (1,7) for example
```

7. The result is then joined using `.join` like you used it in the original post
8. `continue` tells the `while` loop to move to *continue* its work. Think of it as `return` for functions.